# GPUImage slow memory accumulation

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I looked at forums to locate similar questions, but it seems that my issue is different.
I am using GPUImage, I built framework using bash script. I looked at samples of creating filters & their chain for processing. 
But in my app I am facing constant increase in memory consumption. There are no memory leaks, I profiled my app.

image - is an image taken from the camera. I call the code described bellow in for loop. I do witness memory increase starting from 7MB, to 150MB, after than the app is terminated.

Here is the code :

```
- (void)processImageInternal:(UIImage *)image
{
    GPUImagePicture * picture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc]initWithImage:image];

    GPUImageLanczosResamplingFilter *lanczosResamplingFilter = [GPUImageLanczosResamplingFilter new];

    CGFloat scale = image.scale;
    CGSize size = image.size;
    CGFloat newScale = roundf(2*scale);
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake((size.width *scale)/newScale,(size.height *scale)/newScale);

    [lanczosResamplingFilter forceProcessingAtSize:newSize];

    [picture addTarget:lanczosResamplingFilter];

    GPUImageGrayscaleFilter * grayScaleFilter = [GPUImageGrayscaleFilter new];
    [grayScaleFilter forceProcessingAtSize:newSize];

    [lanczosResamplingFilter addTarget:grayScaleFilter];

    GPUImageMedianFilter * medianFilter = [GPUImageMedianFilter new];
    [medianFilter forceProcessingAtSize:newSize];

    [grayScaleFilter addTarget:medianFilter];

    GPUImageSharpenFilter * sharpenFilter  = [GPUImageSharpenFilter new];
    sharpenFilter.sharpness +=2.0;
    [sharpenFilter forceProcessingAtSize:newSize];

    [medianFilter addTarget:sharpenFilter];

    GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter * blurFilter = [GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter new];
    blurFilter.blurSize = 0.5;
    [blurFilter forceProcessingAtSize:newSize];

    [sharpenFilter addTarget:blurFilter];

    GPUImageUnsharpMaskFilter * unsharpMask = [GPUImageUnsharpMaskFilter new];
    [unsharpMask forceProcessingAtSize:newSize];

    [blurFilter addTarget:unsharpMask];

    [picture processImage];

    image = [unsharpMask imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
 }
```

The code is executed in background thread.

Here is calling code:

```
for (NSUInteger i=0;i <100;i++)
{
    NSLog(@" INDEX OF I : %d",i);
    [self processImageInternal:image];
}
```

I even added some cleanup logic into `- (void)processImageInternal:(UIImage *)image` method
     - (void)processImageInternal:(UIImage *)image
      {
        .........
       [picture processImage];

```
   image = [unsharpMask imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];

  //clean up code....

  [picture removeAllTargets];

    [self releaseResourcesForGPUOutput:unsharpMask];
    [self releaseResourcesForGPUOutput:blurFilter];
    [self releaseResourcesForGPUOutput:sharpenFilter];
    [self releaseResourcesForGPUOutput:medianFilter];
    [self releaseResourcesForGPUOutput:lanczosResamplingFilter];
    [self releaseResourcesForGPUOutput:grayScaleFilter];
```

In release method, basically I am releasing whatever is possible to release: FBO, textures, targets. Here is the code:

```
- (void)releaseResourcesForGPUOutput:(GPUImageOutput *) output
{
  if ([output isKindOfClass:[GPUImageFilterGroup class]])
  {
    GPUImageFilterGroup *group = (GPUImageFilterGroup *) output;

    for (NSUInteger i=0; i<group.filterCount;i++)
    {
        GPUImageFilter *  curFilter = (GPUImageFilter * )[group filterAtIndex:i];

        [self releaseResourcesForGPUFilter:curFilter];
    }
    [group removeAllTargets];
  }
  else if ([output isKindOfClass:[GPUImageFilter class]])
  {
    [self releaseResourcesForGPUFilter:(GPUImageFilter *)output];
  }
}
```

Unsharp mask it GPU group filters, i.e. composite of filters.

```
- (void)releaseResourcesForGPUFilter:(GPUImageFilter *)filter
{
  if ([filter respondsToSelector:@selector(releaseInputTexturesIfNeeded)])
  {
    [filter releaseInputTexturesIfNeeded];
    [filter destroyFilterFBO];
    [filter cleanupOutputImage];
    [filter deleteOutputTexture];
    [filter removeAllTargets];
  }
}
```

I did as Brad suggested to do: My code was called in UI touch processing loop. Autorealized pool objects are drained, but from Allocation Instruments I cannot see anything strange. But my application is terminated. 
Total allocation was 130 MB at the end, but for some reasons my apps was terminated.
Here is how it looks like: ( I placed screen shots, log from device, even trace from Instruments). My app is called TesseractSample, but I completely switched off tesseract usage, even its' initialisation.

http://goo.gl/w5XrVb

In log from device I see that there maximum allow rpages were used:

http://goo.gl/ImG2Wt

But I do not have an clue what it means. rpages == recent_max ( 167601)

Comment: Camera's image is received from iOS's UIImagePickerController.

Comment: Code was tested on iPhone 4S,(iOS 7.0.2), and on iPhone 5( iOS 5.1) behaviour is the same.

Comment: Try making your -processImageInternal: method be triggered on a button press, and then run your application in the Allocations instrument, taking a heap shot after every time you touch that button. That should reveal whatever is accumulating in memory.

Comment: Many thanks Brad, I did as u suggest by I do not understand results (

Comment: What I meant is that you need to mark the heap at regular points before these operations and see what accumulates. In your screenshot from Instruments, do you see the button on the left-hand side of the screen that says "Mark Generation"? Move the tracking head in the timeline above to right after each one of those big spikes you see in the timeline and click that button to mark the heap at that point. Do this after each of these spikes. The Allocations instrument will then tell you what objects accumulated after each of these operations, which should help identify any buildup.

Comment: Ah,I see. But from marked generations, I observe that too many times Two Pass filter is used, as far as I understand it comes from Unsharp mask filter

Comment: Here is the image: [link]http://goo.gl/NMUzEM

Comment: Another part: http://goo.gl/XxEVgJ

Comment: And the last one: http://goo.gl/cmwRG4

Comment: Those still don't tell me anything. When you mark the heap, it will present you with a list of generations, with the number of objects from within that generation still alive when the application was terminated. Read through Bill's description of the process here: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/ . You want to look at that list and see the allocations from the middle few heap shots to see what is really accumulating between passes.